# Why Ruby doesn’t provide a `Complexe#modulo` method?

Tags: ruby, modulo, complex-numbers

Ruby defines `Numeric#%`, aka `Numeric#modulo` to provide the remaining of receiver divided by an other Numeric. However, as the code bellow show, `Complex` is the only derived type which doesn’t provide a method for it:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class){p "#{_1}: #{_1.method_defined?(:%)}" if _1.ancestors.include?(Numeric) unless _1 == Numeric}
"Complex: false"
"Rational: true"
"Float: true"
"Integer: true"
"Date::Infinity: true"
```

Is there a mathematical reason to avoid providing a reminder of complex numbers? In all cases, is there a documented reason for this engineering design choice?

Provision of an implementation of this operator for Complex, highlighting possible pitfall avoided if any, would also be welcome but more marginal for the topic of this question.

Side note: this as nothing to do with the notion of complex [modulus](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html), aka norm, which is also absent from Ruby standard library.

Comment: Matz says in [Bug #1712](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1712): _"I don't think there's natural definition of modulo on complex numbers, so that we should undefine `%` method."_

Comment: I think that definitely answer why it’s not there. Although looking at resources like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274694/modulo-complex-number other people have a different point of view of modulo over complexes. But that’s an other story. @Stefan please put your feedback as an answer so I can validate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in 2009, in [Bug #1712](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1712), Matz says:

> I don't think there's natural definition of modulo on complex numbers, so that we should undefine `%` method.

As a result, `Complex` doesn't have `%`, `modulo`, or `divmod`. (among [others](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_3_1/complex.c#L2334-L2345))