# How can Ruby `Complex` class have `Comparable` in its ancestors when it has none of its relational operator except `==`?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, ruby-comparable

Indeed:

```rb
Comparable.instance_methods # => [:clamp, :<=, :>=, :==, :<, :>, :between?]
Complex.ancestors # => [Complex, Numeric, Comparable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
Complex.instance_methods.select{Comparable.instance_methods.include? _1} # => [:==]
```

Of course, `==` is also defined in BasicObject, so even `==` doesn't count that much.

How is that possible? Can you *remove* an ancestor method in Ruby?

Is it possible to remove methods at all?

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_1_2/complex.c#L2334

Comment: Excellent @Stefan, much thanks, that actually help me much as it seems that Complex is the sole class which has these methods removed (in the standard library)

Comment: Still, an interesting question remains: Why then is `Complex` including `Comparable`?

Comment: @user1934428 `Complex` includes `Numeric` which in turn includes `Comparable`. If you want `Numeric` without `Comparable`, undefining the methods is the (only) way to go.

Comment: Sure, I would love to get some light on this. The topic is mentionned in https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-master/repository/git/revisions/98286e9850936e27e8ae5e4f20858cc9c13d2dde so it is a choice that doesn't seem to trigger any question for the VM maintainers, but it doesn't really give a clue of why this makes sense.

Comment: @Stefan: I hope that `Complex` does not **include** `Numeric`, but **inherits** from `Numeric`. In any case, this looks like a design flow in the Ruby standard library. If a `Numeric` is supposed to be `Comparable`, the idea of inheritance is broken (violating [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). I don't know why the Ruby designers decided in this way, but it is certainly good to know that we have to live with it.

Comment: For your information, @user1934428, `Complex` also removes `#%`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71439853/1307778 for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a method in two ways, [`undef_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#undef_method-method) and [`remove_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#remove_method-method)

`undef_method` will remove the ability to call the method competely, but `remove_method` will remove just the current method, letting you fall back to the super method if it exists.

```
class Foo
  undef_method :bar
end
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Now, I came to the question as I made aliases to `Comparable` methods, and `Complex` also inherits them, but as they are tied to the Comparable class, it doesn't generate the same behavior: 

```ruby
1i < 1i # undefined method `<' for (0+1i):Complex (NoMethodError)
# #ere? aliases #< 
1i.ere? 1i # `<': comparison of Complex with Complex failed (ArgumentError)
```

Is it possible to remove inherited aliases? If yes, I guess I could go through ObjectSpace and remove target aliases when current method was undefined, or maybe there is some more efficient way.

Comment: Ho it looks like `undef_method` does the work for aliases too, actually.